# Select records by date create in interval between certain time for everyday | MYSQL

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I need to get records by it time creating in interval between 9:00 and 20:00 for everyday in Sql request.

`t.date_create` fields are stored in Unix time.

I guess the request must looks like something like below:

```
SELECT count(t.id) as count 
FROM products as t
WHERE hour(FROM_UNIXTIME('t.date_create', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i')) >= 9 and hour(FROM_UNIXTIME('t.date_create', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i')) <= 20
```

But it doesn' work.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needed the request below works for me just fine.

```
WHERE day(from_unixtime(t.date_create,  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) = day(CURDATE())
AND   hour(from_unixtime(t.date_create, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) BETWEEN 9 AND 20
```